# Merge datasets in R by similiar (but not the same) row names

Tags: merge, row, names, approximation

I have two datasets about cities' names, states (uf), and years. The main problem is that their names are written in different forms in these datasets. The only correct thing between them is the year and the state.

```
year    uf  municipality
2013    RO  Ariquemes
2018    RO  Ariquemes
2020    RO  Ariquemes
2017    RO  Ariquemes
2015    RO  Ariquemes
2019    RO  Ariquemes
2016    RO  Ariquemes
2014    RO  Ariquemes
2018    RO  Cabixi
2017    RO  Cabixi
2019    RO  Cabixi
2013    RO  Cabixi
2020    RO  Cabixi
2016    RO  Cabixi
2014    RO  Cabixi
2015    RO  Cabixi
2019    RO  Cacoal
2018    RO  Cacoal
2017    RO  Cacoal

count   year    uf  municipality
2   2015    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - COLATINA
9   2016    ES  1ª Vara da Infância e Juventude - VILA VELHA
3   2014    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - LINHARES
11  2014    ES  1ª Vara da Infância e Juventude - SERRA
2   2013    ES  2ª Vara - IBIRAÇU
3   2013    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - ITAPEMIRIM
1   2013    ES  2ª Vara da Comarca de Afonso Cláudio
3   2017    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - CACHOEIRO DE ITAPEMIRIM
1   2015    ES  2ª Vara - CONCEIÇÃO DA BARRA
1   2013    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - LINHARES
4   2015    ES  Vara de Infância e Juventude - CACHOEIRO DE ITAPEMIRIM
1   2015    ES  Vara Única - JAGUARÉ
1   2013    ES  2ª Vara - ALEGRE
1   2013    ES  2ª Vara - PANCAS
2   2014    ES  2ª Vara - PANCAS
11  2018    ES  1ª Vara da Infância e Juventude - SERRA
4   2021    MG  2 VARA CIVEL, CRIMINAL E DA INFANCIA E DA JUVENTUDE DA COMARCA DE GUANHAES
```

I want to do the following: Using R, I would like to merge these datasets by municipality uf and year, but there must be a way to approximate the names of the municipalities, which are written differently. I know that it would be something like:

```
base <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by=c("year", "municipality", "uf"))
```

However, as the names in "municipality" are not exact the same, I keep getting an error. How do I solve this issue?